# wpf sorting combobox item in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have got combobox. The items within this combobox is coming from database and I am trying to sort it in alphabetical order but unable to do so. Can someone please help figuring out how this can be achieved?

```
private ObservableCollection<StudentModules> modules;

public StudentModule()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Modules = new ObservableCollection<StudentModules>();
            ModuleNames.ItemsSource = modules;

            IDataAccess<ModulesFinder, StudentModules> moduleRetriever = ((IDataManager)Application.Current.Properties["Database”]).GetDataAccessor<ModuleFinder, StudentModules>();

            foreach (StudentModules module in retrieve.AllItems())
            {
                Modules.Add(module);
            }   
        }
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="ModuleNames" >
                    <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
                        <Binding Path="ModuleDetails" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <validators:IsMandatoryValidation FieldName="Module Names"/>
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
                </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tries so far?

Comment: You should mention whether is it winform or wpf or other kind of application  in your question

Comment: @viveknuna judging by the presence of XAML I'd say it was WPF

Comment: yes but initially he has not written code. and I started writing code for winforms. I was about to post my answer for winforms , then I saw its for wpf

Comment: You can try ordering before adding to Modules, on the foreach, put retrieve.AllItems().OrderBy(x => x.Name)

Answer (score 11):

You should use a [`CollectionViewSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx).

**XAML:**

You'll need to import the `System.ComponentModel` namespace as **scm**.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ModulesViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=Modules}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
       <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
  </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>

...

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ModulesViewSource}}" />
```